Gravitational wave flux in Effective One-Body (EOB) models
I'm working for my M2 internship on gravitational waves in effective one-body approach, and I'm struggling in understanding how they compute the non-conservative flux from GW radiations. Most of the articles I'm working on are from T. Damour, and he uses this formula:
$$
\mathcal{F}_\varphi = -\frac{1}{\Omega}\frac{2}{16 \pi G}\sum_{\ell=2}^{\ell_{max}}\sum_{m = 1}^\ell (m \Omega)^2 |R h_{\ell m}|^2
$$
And then, another formula for $h_{\ell m}$, for Newtonian and Post Newtonian approximations.
I have two questions. What is $|Rh|$? I'm pretty sure that $R$ is not the radius but something like "radiated", but I can't find a clear answer in Damour articles. And how can I translate $h_{lm}$ quantities to a GW signal? I've found something like $h(t) = \sum {h_{\ell m}} _{-2} Y_{\ell m}$, is it so simple?

Link to abstract page for article?

I'm not sure which Damour paper you are referring to, so I'm using this 2012 review of the EOB formalism by Damour.
In the Newtonian two-body problem, it is possible to map the two-body dynamics onto a particle with reduced mass $\mu = \frac{m_1 m_2}{m_1 + m_2}$ orbiting a fixed central total mass $M= m_1 + m_2$ located at the system center of mass.  The same idea is worked out in the EOB approach.  In GR the symmetric mass ratio $\nu = \frac{\mu}{M}$ is a third important mass variable.
The point of the EOB formalism is to solve for the GW waveform from two-body systems, like binary black holes.  You can break it down into a kind of time-stepping, where EOB dynamics at time $t_1$ are used find the GW $h$.  Then $h(t_1)$ tells you the radiation reaction force $\mathcal{F}(t_1)$, which allows you to step the dynamics forward to $t_2$.
I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the radiation reaction force equation.  If you already know $h(t)$, you could calculate the time evolving radiation reaction force the system experiences, but I don't know why that's useful.
In equation (11), $R$ first appears as the radial coordinate of the effective Schwarzschild metric.  The effective Schwarzschild metric is based on the total mass, and the radial coordinate $R$ tells us a position relative to the center of mass of the system.
In equation (34) the GW strain $h$ comes in with a prefactor proportional to $\frac{1}{R}$.  The strain is weaker the further from the source you are.  The factor $|Rh|$ removes this scaling. The energy radiated that leads to the radiation reaction force $\mathcal{F}$ depends on the "shape" of the waveform, but not how far away an observer is.
The $h_{\ell m}$ is the GW strain expanded out in a spherical harmonic basis.  Different mass ratios and spins will excite different harmonics more or less.  Historically the most attention has been payed to the dominant, quadrupolar $h_{22}$ term.  The full waveform would be an infinite sum of all harmonics, but many will be very low amplitude compared to the dominant.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think the $\ell_\mathrm{max}$ in the sum is showing that in practice you have to truncate the sum somewhere.
